# Why does my new Dell laptop charger make a weird noise?

Tags: dell-xps, charger

Got a brand new dell xps laptop as a gift about 2 months ago and the tranformer of my charger is making that weird noise that sound like a cricket! What is that noise ? Should i get a new charger ??

Answer (score 1):

don't worry about it, I have the same 'cricket' sound for 2 and a half years now and the adaptor is still working great.

Answer (score 0):

The sound is caused by vibrations within the various electromagnetic components that make up the power supply. It does not necessarily indicate a problem per se, as the components are usually designed to have some tolerance for vibration and physical distortion. Some companies may offer to replace the power supply though if the noise is excessive.